# Display most popular in the past two days

Tags: wp-query, functions, popular-posts

Hi I'm using this code below to display the most popular post on my wordpress site. It works great! I was wondering if there was anyway to show the most popular post of the current day?

This in my `functions.php`

```
function getPostViews($postID){
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    return "0 View";
}
return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
}
else{
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
}
}
```

and this in my theme file

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<li><?php setPostViews(get_the_ID()); echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: That would require you to save the counts in a separate meta with today's date in the key, then select. example `'post_views_count_' . date('d-m-Y')` and when updating `post_views_count` also update this one. Guess now that would be easier to do the rest..

Comment: I'm not completely understanding what you are saying @SamuelElh

Comment: Let me write you some code to try out.. That would be easier than these tiny comments.

Comment: I would appreciate that @SamuelElh

Comment: see this http://pastebin.com/DBA8remL (Please read the code comments)

Comment: Thank you It works, I will try some of these things from the comments code to and If I have a problem is it okay to contact you @SamuelElh

Comment: Sure Terrell. It's just a whole lot to put into an answer, you just need to understand it a bit and code it yourself. Please and I will be glad to help with the rest samelh.com/contact/ . I also fixed a small bug in `setPostViews` func, see the paste..

Comment: This code actually doesnt work. I may have to find a new solution @SamuelElh